# How to convert Balsamiq mockups to text strings txt with Python34 script on Windows XP

Tags: python-3.x, balsamiq

I've been trying to run these scripts https://github.com/balsamiq/mockups-strings-extractor within XP. I'm getting errors per this screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/rlbqp1iytkwvq3m/Screenshot%202014-05-30%2011.57.48.png

Also I tried CD into my test directory and although a text output file is generated it is empty and I still get these errors https://www.dropbox.com/s/odjfbr97e5i4gnn/Screenshot%202014-05-30%2012.09.31.png

Is anybody running Balsamiq on windows able to make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) From the looks of the first error pic you included, you were trying to execute a Windows Shell command inside of a Python Interpreter. If you've still got the window open, type `quit()` before attempting your command again.

2) Your script was written for Python 2.x. If you're using Python 3.x, you'll need to add parentheses to the `print` lines in the script file and change `urllib` to `urllib.parse`. I made the changes below:

```
import os
import glob
import re
import urllib.parse

for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(".", '*.bmml') ):
    print("STRINGS FOUND IN " + infile)
    print("===========================================================")
    f = open (infile,"r")
    data = f.read()
    p = re.compile("<text>(.*?)</text>")
    textStrings = p.findall(data)
    print(urllib.parse.unquote('\n'.join(textStrings))+"\n")
    f.close()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I made the changes you suggested and get error per https://www.dropbox.com/s/8yy0i05ll5bbwsv/Screenshot%202014-05-31%2020.59.48.png

Comment: @JulieS.: When stdout is redirected, Python uses the encoding returned by `locale.getpreferredencoding()`, such as Windows code page 1252 in your case. The environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING` overrides this, but it's also simple enough to just rebind `stdout` when output is redirected: `if not sys.stdout.isatty(): sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.detach(), 'utf-8')`. The same applies to `sys.stdin` and `sys.stderr`.

Comment: @eryksun - could you please clarify what I should do step by step ? Where do I place this "rebind" code ?

Comment: @JulieS., rebind `sys.stdout` to the UTF-8 `TextIOWrapper` at the start of your program, before you execute the for loop. You also need `import sys, io` to use those modules. If you don't follow that, just run `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` in the cmd shell to override the default encoding for stdin, stdout, and stderr.

Comment: I did not follow that :) but I did run set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 in the cmd shell and now the string extraction works! Thank you! I will mark this question as answered.

Comment: The script no longer seems to be working as I am getting a 0 kb in the resulting "out.txt"
per https://www.dropbox.com/s/7cjivjce8bvyl93/Screenshot%202014-06-07%2015.52.03.png. I do not believe I changed anything since last week.

Comment: Your dropbox link isn't working. Can you share it again?

Comment: sorry about that - here it is again https://www.dropbox.com/s/7cjivjce8bvyl93/Screenshot%202014-06-07%2015.52.03.png

Comment: I'm gonna guess that you have Python 2.x installed on your computer. Change the first line of your script to `#!/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: Actually, last week before I posted my question I installed Python34 - I do not believe i ever installed Python 2.x. Is there anything I can run to check if Pytyhon 2.x is installed also on the same computer ? Do I need to start the Python interpreter or something instead of running CMD ? @eryksun, any suggestion you may have would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Even if you don't have another version of Python, let me know if the change I suggested works. If it didn't help, see what gets printed to the console if you don't redirect the output to `out.txt`.

Comment: @JulieS., you're running the script with Python 3, else `import urllib.parse` would raise an `ImportError` exception and print a traceback to `stderr`. Change the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/python3` anyway, just in case later on you decide to install 2.x. (FYI, Windows Python 3.3+ associates .py files with py.exe, which parses the shebang line to run a script with the specified interpreter.) To help debug your script, run it without redirecting stdout to `out.txt`, and add `print(textStrings)` to inspect the regex result.

Comment: Eryk , @Samba, thank you. I changed per your suggestions as https://www.dropbox.com/s/uhoewfb3lyxu3k5/Screenshot%202014-06-14%2015.28.08.png - unfortunately still 0kb in output and print(textStrings) also comes out empty.

Comment: @eryksun, unfortunately still 0 kb in output and print(textStrings) also comes out empty.

Comment: @Julie, I'm not sure why your new problem persists. I was able to run the code on my computer without a problem. I confess that I'm more familiar with the inner workings of Python than Windows. I suggest opening a new question; there may be someone with more Windows expertise to help you.